# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, angular14

I am using nvd3 charts(nvd3-1.8.5, d3-3.5.17), facing the below issue after Upgrading from angular 12 to angular 14. When it was in angular 12 I didn't face any issues.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
    at d3.js:8:26
    at 83064 (d3.js:1:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 54058 (index.ts:8:44)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 84096 (settings.saveview.html:41:141)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 70299 (UserServiceResolver.ts:18:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 64349 (viewlogmessage.html:65:57)
```

Even I tried with nvd3 1.8.5 with d3 4.0.0(With Angular 14) getting the below issue.

```
core.mjs:6397 ERROR TypeError: nv.dispatch.render_start is not a function
    at Object.render (nv.d3.js:93:17)
    at nv.addGraph (nv.d3.js:145:12)
    at ViewActionsComponent.ts:169:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ViewActionsComponent.onGetMessageSuccessCallback (ViewActionsComponent.ts:140:11)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (ViewActionsComponent.ts:83:36)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:22)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:26)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:18)
```

Adding package.json configuration for reference.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.2",
    "@types/ace": "0.0.32",
    "@types/angular": "1.6.21",
    "@types/argparse": "1.0.30",
    "@types/ckeditor": "0.0.37",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.47",
    "@types/d3pie": "^0.1.5",
    "@types/glob": "5.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/minimatch": "2.0.29",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.50",
    "@types/nvd3": "^1.8.42",
    "@types/shelljs": "0.7.0",
    "access-sniff": "2.4.61",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "argparse": "1.0.9",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "copyfiles": "1.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "0.27.3",
    "d3": "4.0.0",
    "d3pie": "0.1.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-appender": "^1.1.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "fs-extra": "5.0.0",
    "glob": "7.1.1",
    "glob-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "gnomon": "1.5.0",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "less": "2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "less-plugin-clean-css": "1.5.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.6",
    "ncp": "2.0.0",
    "npm-build-tools": "^2.2.5",
    "nvd3": "1.8.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "0.8.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "0.7.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "rollup-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "shelljs": "0.7.5",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "systemjs": "^6.12.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typedoc": "0.5.7",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "uglify-js": "3.0.26",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.1.10",
    "ace-builds": "^1.4.14",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^26.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.1.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "commonjs-require": "1.4.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.7",
    "es6-collections": "0.5.6",
    "es6-promise": "3.3.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.34.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.0.489",
    "plotly.js": "2.12.1",
    "plugin-typescript": "4.0.17",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-smart-logger": "0.0.4",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.5"
}
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be no a right fix, but

- remove all import d3
- use CDN link in your index.html file:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.7/d3.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-MbgT+83UxCH6sDPhdRyAqCvG+93y1xm6SIC/1T15gWsbkC2bjGqHVWepfhPMocnEOhgXBtZCOxHmwq0XPsqSGQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I've faced same issue, so I took ^ actions.

Regarding types d3 js types, u can have it as dependecies.